# Android Lifecycle Behavior

Tags: android, android-activity, android-lifecycle

Having an issue with lifecycle events and need some help if possible. I have read the other posts with similar issue and error however, still stuck ....  Explaination may be a little long.

I have an App that requires the user to login when any 'backgrounding' event occurs (App switch, screen sleep, phone call and so on).  Previously I was using the method of 'getRunningTasks' to check is my app is no longer top of stack to trigger the login flags and activity.  I am now using a suggested timer method via onPause / onResume in my Application class which works great.

Now the issue at hand, and the questions:

1. App into background by Device Home button.

   - App is in the background, all my checks and flags are properly set.  When I relaunch the app (Icon press), it loads the last activity, then from the onResume function - performs a startIntent for the login activity - based on the flag set in the timer event.   The user logs in, and returns to the activity they were on (Stock List). All Good.
2. App into background by App Switch

   - timer event fires and all login flags are properly done as previous example.
     -->  Click 'device Home'button, then App icon ---  App loads properly and loads the Login Activity, users logs in -- all good.

Problem area

2b. App into background by App Switch  --> Example, Android pull down menu, jump to device settings - then return to app via the device back button

- timer event fires and all login flags are properly done as previous example.
  --> Click device 'return/back' button to return directly to the app.
     User goes to Login screen, clicks 'Login' button - gets app crash due to :

java.lang.RuntimeException: Performing pause of activity that is not resumed
followed by
java.lang.RuntimeException: Performing stop of activity that is not resumed

My own system Logs in the lifecycle events all seem to fire in the appropriate order.

Basic overview from app re-launch:
  ->  DashBoard onResume
         -> check for login flag and call intent for Login activity
      Dashboard onPause
      Login onResume
      Login - user login hit button
      Login onPause --- activity finish
      Return to Dashboard onResume
         -> Load details

The only diff is in the last senario ... the DashBoard onPause happens after the Login onResume. Not sure if this is the problem, or an Async delay issue with the lifecycle events.

My Manifest includes:

```
    android:minSdkVersion="10"     --- Maintaining old API due to clients with older devices
    android:targetSdkVersion="19"
```

Any help or suggestions on what may be out of whack here? or how to avoid this error.

Thanks

--

Some code:

From BaseActivity.java
~~~~~~
    private AppPreferences mAppPrefs;
    protected MyApplication mMyApp;

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
//start timer
    mMyApp.startActivityTransitionTimer();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    //update current Activity Name
    mMyApp.setCurrentActivity(this);
    mMyApp.stopActivityTransitionTimer();

    mAppPrefs = new AppPreferences(getApplicationContext());
    if (mAppPrefs.getAppDestroyed() == true
            || mAppPrefs.getExitType() == AppPreferences.EXITTYPE_FULLEXIT) {
        // we want to fully exit/close the app
       this.finish();
    } else {
        if (mAppPrefs.getForceLoginState() == true) {
            //~~~~ process login events
           Intent intent = new Intent(this, LoginScreen.class);                     
           startActivity(intent);
           return;
        }
    }
}


DashboardActivity extends BaseActivity
{

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    if (((MyApplication)this.getApplication()).getProcessingLogout()){
        // if we are already processing a login, do not continue here
            return;
    }

    // ~~~ activity specific onPause event such as unregisterReceivers

    ((MyApplication)this.getApplication()).startActivityTransitionTimer();
 }


@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    if (((MyApplication)this.getApplication()).getProcessingLogout()){
        // if we are already processing a login, do not continue here
        return;
    }

    // ~~~ activity specific onResume events such as registerReceivers


}

}
```

Comment: Could you show us the relevant code in `onStop()`, `onResume()` etc.?

Comment: Are you calling `finish()` or something like that in any of the lifecycle callbacks?

Comment: Some code added.  onStop is not being used for controlling the timer or checking the loginRequired flag.